# Sort tab-completion suggestions (files first, then directories) in vim command line

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, command-line, autocompletion

When i go to command mode, type `:e`  and press `tab`, i get like this

> Excuse the file, directory writings on the right side (used for explanation)

```
A.cpp              file
Adamwathan/        directory
bucky.cpp          file
caleb/             directory
e.cpp              file
note.txt           file
vimtmp/            directory
```

I know about `wildignore` to ignore some files or directories.. and everything 
but couldn't find anything to sort between files and directories

According to my need, i want **files first, then directories** sorted

```
A.cpp
bucky.cpp
e.cpp
note.txt
Adamwathan/
caleb/
vimtmp/
```

Can anyone help me make this config? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `:help cmdline-completion` section, see this paragraph discusses `suffixes`

```
                            *c_CTRL-D*
CTRL-D      List names that match the pattern in front of the cursor.
        When showing file names, directories are highlighted (see
        'highlight' option).  Names where 'suffixes' matches are moved
        to the end.
        The 'wildoptions' option can be set to "tagfile" to list the
        file of matching tags.
```

Then jumping to the `:help suffixes` page:

```
                        *'suffixes'* *'su'*
'suffixes' 'su'     string  (default ".bak,~,.o,.h,.info,.swp,.obj")
            global
    Files with these suffixes get a lower priority when multiple files
    match a wildcard.  See |suffixes|.  Commas can be used to separate the
    suffixes.  Spaces after the comma are ignored.  A dot is also seen as
    the start of a suffix.  To avoid a dot or comma being recognized as a
    separator, precede it with a backslash (see |option-backslash| about
    including spaces and backslashes).
```

Using this, you can include `/` in the `suffixes` option.  You probably want to pre-pend this to the default option, using `^=`

```
:set suffixes^=/
:set suffixes?
  suffixes=/,.bak,~,.o,.h,.info,.swp,.obj
```

With the default setting for `suffixes`, hitting `<tab>` after `:e` would show everything in alphabetical order:

```
:e
abc.vim  bbb/     def.vim  xyz.vim  yo/      ze/
```

After pre-pending `/` to the `suffixes` setting, the directories show up last:

```
:e
abc.vim  def.vim  xyz.vim  bbb/     yo/      ze/
```

Comment: if i'm not wrong, this works on all machines.. but doesn't work in nvim-qt on windows :(

Comment: Is that because the directories are not listed with a backslash at the end?   Is there another character or characters you could use to specify the end of a windows directory?

Comment: here's an example. I use this in my .vimrc set backupdir=C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\vimtmp\\
I tried 4 suffixes /,//,\,\\ all four but still no luck

Comment: I would've thought that \\ would've been sufficient.   Try \\\\.   See `:help option-backslash`.

Comment: still doesn't work